# How to send email in R that read csv and send multiple email at once?

Tags: r, email

I have CSV file that contains email.
How to send multiple email in r ?

Error 1
send.mail function not taking data.frame values

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  Sorry, parameter type `NA' is ambiguous or not supported.
```

Error 2
function not taking input from read.table

```
Error in file.exists(body) : invalid 'file' argument
```

My code as below (credentials as an example only)

```
temp <- read.csv("E:/OneDrive/M.Tech/temp.csv",header = FALSE)
m <- data.frame(temp)
email <- m[2,14]
rollno <- m[2,1]

file <- read.table("C:/Mehul Katara/New folder (2)/131004.txt",header =  TRUE,sep = ";")

send.mail(from = "user@gmail.com",
          to = email,
          subject = rollno,
          body = file,        
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "user@gmail.com", passwd = "password", ssl = TRUE),              
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Comment: yes email credentials are fake just for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is just one error with this. Use:

```
file <- read.table("C://Mehul Katara//New folder (2)//131004.txt",header =  TRUE,sep = ";")
```

So you need to change `/` in path to `//` because of R windows binary behavior. Above path may also not work but in that case you need to get rid of spaces as in "MehulKatara". Please put your file in another place where there is no space in filepath. Error 1 is coming just because of error 2 and should go as soon as you fix error 2.

From the documentation

> **body** Body of the email as text. If the parameter body refers to an
>   existing file location, the text of the file is parsed as body of the
>   email.

so ideally you should change call of function to something like:

```
send.mail(from = "user@gmail.com",
          to = email,
          subject = rollno,
          body ="C://Mehul_Katara//New_folder_(2)//131004.txt"
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "user@gmail.com", passwd = "password", ssl = TRUE),              
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Comment: reading file from given path is OK. How to store that file in variable file ? send.mail() function not recognize that file.