# Tableau Server Automating reports

Tags: tableau-api

I have many tableau workbooks on our tableau server.  I want to automate these workbooks and print them to PDF and email them to specific people. 
Could anyone help me with this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Still there is no option to publish automatically but you can do it with some trick below

there few requirement before you get start.

- Your viewer need static IP address so we can access tableau without login and download pdf file [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086871/how-to-access-tableau-server-without-login).
- Little knowledge programming i.e. R or Python to send email and hit link to download file [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670016/how-to-send-email-in-r-that-read-csv-and-send-multiple-email-at-once)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Tableau REST API for this task - there is a feature currently being voted on here: https://community.tableau.com/ideas/5025

This post here has more details for you about a potential workaround that might suit your needs: https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-8361